# Blacklist attributes sent to the Chef server

Tags: chef-infra, ohai-gem

Due to the fact that i have a large volume of users and groups present on my chef nodes, running chef-client sends all that information to the chef server, causing performance issues.

I can whitelist attributes easily by adding something like this on client.rb :automatic_attribute_whitelist ["etc/group"]

Is there any way to blacklist a specific set of attributes from being sent to the Chef server?

Comment: https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/whitelist-node-attrs

Comment: What type of attributes?

Comment: I simply need to exclude the etc/group & etc/passwd node attributes that get sent during each node converge. Whitelisting implies that you specify which attributes you want to keep. It would be a lot simpler if I could simply exclude two attributes and not worry about the rest.

Comment: Why don't you just disable that particular Ohai plugin? http://stevendanna.github.io/blog/2013/04/13/passwd-min-ohai-plugin/

Comment: That did the trick. Submit it as an answer so I can accept (although this is more of a work around and doesn't specify if chef actually supports blacklisted node attributes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All my comments, as an answer (plus an actual answer).

You can [disable the Ohai plugin for passwd](http://stevendanna.github.io/blog/2013/04/13/passwd-min-ohai-plugin/) if you aren't using those attributes or are connected to an AD.

If you want the attributes available on the `node` object, but not persisted back to the server, you can do something like this in a cookbook:

```
class Chef
  class Node
    alias_method :old_save, :save

    def save
      self.default_attrs.delete(:key)
      self.normal_attrs.delete(:other_key)
      self.override_attrs.delete('...')
      self.automatic_attrs.delete('...')
      old_save
    end
  end
end
```

This would get rather annoying for long lists of attributes, so IRCCloud make a cookbook for it:

- https://github.com/irccloud/blacklist-node-attrs

Comment: Excellent recommendation.